# Key Error: 0 in Python with edit distance

Tags: python, keyerror

Could someone please let me know why I am getting a "Key Error: 0" message with reference to line 23 for the following code? I am trying to implement an edit distance function, returning the cost and the last operation. Thanks!

```
from enum import Enum


class Operation(Enum):
    """Operations"""

    DELETED = 1
    INSERTED = 2
    SUBSTITUTED = 3

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name.lower())


def distances(a, b):
    """Calculate edit distance from a to b"""

    # edit distance
    x = len(a) + 1
    y = len(b) + 1
    cost = {}
    for i in range(0, x):
        cost[i][0] = i
    for j in range(0, y):
        cost[0][j] = j
    for i in range(1, x):
        for j in range(1, y):
            if a[i] == b[j]:
                sub_cost = 0
            else:
                sub_cost = 1
            cost[i][j] = min(cost[i - 1][j] + 1, cost[i][j - 1] + 1, cost[i - 1][j - 1] + sub_cost)

            # final operation
            if cost[i - 1][j] + 1 == min(cost[i - 1][j] + 1, cost[i][j - 1] + 1, cost[i - 1][j - 1] + sub_cost):
                last_operation = Operation.DELETED
            if cost[i][j - 1] + 1 == min(cost[i - 1][j] + 1, cost[i][j - 1] + 1, cost[i - 1][j - 1] + sub_cost):
                last_operation = Operation.INSERTED
            else:
                last_operation = Operation.SUBSTITUTED


    return cost[x][y], last_operation
```

Comment: which line specifically?

Comment: Could you please mark the line where the error is reported in your code?

Comment: The error message was showing with reference to the line "cost[i][0] = i", but now after making the change suggested by Sam Hollenbach's reply, the same error message is showing with regard to the last line.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you run `cost[i][0] = i` on an empty dictionary, you are trying assign a value to a *sub*-dictionary, but since you have not initialized any values in your dictionary yet, there is nothing to access, hence the 'Key Error'. You must initialize the sub-dictionary before you can add a key/value to it

```
for i in range(0, x):
    cost[i] = {}
    cost[i][0] = i
```

Or you could use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to set a default value of sub-items in your dictionary.